# Power BI :: why SWITCH doesn't allows me to select columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have created a dashboard with a `SWITCH` that can allows me to change one table column from USD to CHF.

- [.PBIX](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUmKVvENptNpCA_H7vbA?e=BK9Ds1)
- [.CSV](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUmKVuGLIdebU5wTmvHw?e=YVHkgf)

the goal was to try to avoid Bookmarks which I hate.

But I don't like the solution because I had to create 2 useless metrics:

- `Cost_in_Dollars = SUM('Currency'[costInPricingCurrency])`
- `Cost_in_Francs = SUM('Currency'[costInBillingCurrency])`

These ae just metrics that reproduce the exact same columns for no reason!

And after that I was able to create the Switch:

```
Selected Name = 
SWITCH (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Option[Name] ),
    "Dollars", [Cost_in_Dollars],
    "Francs", [Cost_in_Francs])
```

This because the switch wouldn't allow me to use the columns `[costInPricingCurrency]` and `[costInBillingCurrency]` directly.

Why in the hell the switch doesn't work if I use:

```
Selected Name = 
SWITCH (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Option[Name] ),
    "Dollars", [costInPricingCurrency],
    "Francs", [costInBillingCurrency])
```

So the code is overall working.

I just want to understand why do I have to create a metrics instead of using the column directly.

I find this very stupid.

Can you explain, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DAX, `IF` and `SWITCH` can only return a scalar value, they can't return tables or columns.

You could change it to:

```
Selected Name = 
  SWITCH (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Option[Name] ),
    "Dollars", SUM('Currency'[costInPricingCurrency]),
    "Francs", SUM('Currency'[costInBillingCurrency])
  )
```

Comment: This works and you teach me something. Thank you